# Gmap4Rails.direction in a partial render via AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I have a list where I show some places with the distance from the given address. This list is updated by ajax when the filtering system is used. In my partial _place.html.haml I use this:

```
- distance = Gmaps4rails.destination({:from => session[:address], :to => place.full_address}, options={}, output='pretty')
    %p= "Distance: #{distance.first["distance"]["text"]} (#{distance.first["duration"]["text"]})"
```

Now when I submit my filter form with ajax ( using pjax for this ) the ajax call is done correctly but after rendering the partial via ajax the page is refreshed full ( without ajax ) after the call to the function Gmaps4rails.destination. So it brakes the ajax call/function.

When I delete this code from my partial _place.html.haml the ajax filtering function is working perfect and the full page isn't refreshed. What should I do/change to get this working with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not get your issue completely, but from the description, it looks like you are using pjax and also showing map with some filter-condition.

I have also used pjax and google-map in one application.

Scenario: on single page i have two tabs, at tab-switch i used pjax to load content within same divs. on both tabs i want to show map, both tabs were using same map container, So issue i faced was, pjax ran successfully, but map was not loading. (to load map markers i added ajax call which was getting executed but not reflecting properly.)

Solution:
add pjax:end event

```
$("#your-div").bind 'pjax:end', ->
  # load you markers or call gmap related event
```

So once your pjax gets completed, your map related event would occur.

This may not be the direct solution to your issue. But hope this would help.
Thanks.